# Firebase can't get my input value for auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to make an entry system with Firebase, but I can't read the values entered into input. By the way, Firebase functions on the console when I tried the result is successful.

But it seems something's wrong, and I don't know where you are. as an example, I downloaded it from somewhere and it doesn't work here when I'm working there.

I need help guys thanks

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        if(user != null){
            const email_id = user.email;
            console.log("Welcome User: " + email_id)
        }
    } else {
        console.log("No one here.");
    }
});


function userlogin(){
    const user_email = document.getElementById("user_email").valueOf();
    const user_pass  = document.getElementById("user_pass").valueOf();
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user_email, user_pass).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        window.alert("Error : " + errorMessage);
    });
}
```

```html
  <div class="container" style="margin-top:10%;">
      <div class="row main-div" id="login_area">
          <div class="col-md-5">
              <h3 class="text-center">Chairboard Login</h3><br><br>
              <form role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <input placeholder="E-Mail Address" type="email" class="form-control" id="chair_email" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <input placeholder="Password" type="password" class="form-control" id="chair_pass" />
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="chairLogin()">Login to Account</button>
              </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top: 5%; margin-bottom: 5%;"></div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
              <h3 class="text-center">Delegate Login</h3><br><br>
              <form role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <input placeholder="E-Mail Address" type="email" class="form-control" id="user_email"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <input placeholder="Password" type="password" class="form-control" id="user_pass"/>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="userlogin()">Login to Account</button>
              </form>
          </div>

      </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.0/firebase.js"></script>
  <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      const config = {
          apiKey: "xxx",
          authDomain: "xxx",
          databaseURL: "xxx",
          projectId: "xxx",
          storageBucket: "xxx",
          messagingSenderId: "xxx"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
      console.log("Firebase Loaded");
  </script>
  <script src="app/sign.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the value of email and password, so

```
const user_email = document.getElementById("user_email").valueOf();
const user_pass  = document.getElementById("user_pass").valueOf();
```

should become

```
const user_email = document.getElementById("user_email").value;
const user_pass  = document.getElementById("user_pass").value;
```

Comment: nah, just reloaded the page but when write the signin code
`firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user_email, user_pass)`
to console it was working.

Comment: also, I got a question mark on my link bar so for auth in firebase did we need some actions? like, redirect to another page.

Comment: you have `<button type="submit">` inside a form, so when you click the button, it is submitting the form and causing a refresh. Check out [preventDefault](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp).

Comment: Reload problem has been solved and loaded successfully when the form tags are deleted. Thanks for taking the time out for me!